How to position the node with TikZ.positioning relative to specific angle?
I want to put a node relative to another with the position of 60° left below, just as follows.
I want to shift the slope from 45 degree to 60 degree elegantly (without explicitly assigning the absolute coordinates). But it seems to be no angle interface (just like below left with 45°) in tikz.positionings, is that a good solution?

\documentclass[border=8pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        every node/.style={draw, circle, inner sep=5pt, outer sep=0pt, fill=cyan!20}
    ]
        \node (O) {$1$};
        \node (A) [below left=of O] {$2$} edge (O);
        \node (B) [below left=of A] {$3$} edge (A);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Sorry, still find your drawing AND verbal description contradicting each other. Doe you want it like this, assuming appropriate lengths?  https://i.sstatic.net/H3pUzKPO.png

@MS-SPO what I want is as Paul Gaborit's solution, my 45 degree is just to illstruate the default behaviour of below left.

If you still want to use the advantages of the positioning library, we can create an angle = {<angle>}{<of>} key that works like all the other keys, i.e. it takes the distance between the borders of the nodes and not the one between the centers (well, unless on grid is set, of course).
We can also use that with the chains library.
Code
\documentclass[border=8pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{angle/.code 2 args=\pgfmathsincos{#1}\tikz@lib@place@handle@{#2}{180+#1}{\pgfmathresultx}{\pgfmathresulty}{#1}{1}}
\makeatother

\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\tikzset{60 below left/.style={angle={240}{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw, circle, inner sep=5pt, outer sep=0pt, fill=cyan!20}]
\node (O) {$1$};
\node (A) [angle={240}{of O}] {$2$} edge (O);
\node (B) [angle={240}{of A}] {$3$} edge (A);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={draw, circle, inner sep=5pt, outer sep=0pt, fill=cyan!20},
  start chain=going 60 below left,
  every on chain/.style={join}]
\foreach \v in {1, 2, 3}
  \node[on chain] {\v};
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikz[node distance=1.5cm and 3cm, nodes={draw, circle}, on grid]
  \draw ellipse [x radius=3cm, y radius=1.5cm] node (O) {O}
    node foreach \ang in {0, 30, ..., 359}[angle={\ang}{of O}]{\ang};
\end{document}

Output


Elegant solution! Thanks a Lot!

I get to know and learn the tikz-ext these days, and I'm curious about that whether the above wheels of positioning will be put into tikz-ext? aha~

You can use the calc library and a distance modifiers (cf. section 13.5.4 The Syntax of Distance Modifiers in pgfmanual):
\documentclass[border=8pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc} % <----
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style={draw, circle, inner sep=5pt, outer sep=0pt, fill=cyan!20}
  ]
  \node (O) {$1$};
  \node (A) [below left=of O] {$2$} edge (O);
  \node (B) [below left=of A] {$3$} edge (A);
  \node (C) at ($(O)!1!60-45:(B)$) {$4$} edge (O); % <----
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


variant (required by comment)
You can use the calc library and the coordinate system canvas polar with its implicit form (angle:distance):
\documentclass[border=8pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style={draw, circle, inner sep=5pt, outer sep=0pt, fill=cyan!20}
  ]
  \node (O) {$1$};
  \node (A) at ($(O)+(-120:2cm)$) {$2$} edge (O); <-- first method
  \node (B) at ([shift={(-120:2cm)}]A) {$3$} edge (A); <-- second method
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



May be I didn't make it clearly, I want to pivot the 1-2-3 to 60° position(in yr answer the 4), without explicitly draw the node 1-2-3, and my problem is rooted in limited function of option like below left, it can only change the position by JUST 45°, or just by shift diatance.

Oh, such an elegant solution! I first met that the (point) can calculate with the relative coordinates! Thanks a lot!
