How to automatically label through the dodecagon with TikZ elegantly?
My Final Propose is to draw a picture as below. I tried with the wheels created by Qrrbrbirlbel:

With miminum size and the outer sep option, something went wrong with the float calculation causing errors.
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/729843/how-to-position-the-node-with-tikz-positioning-relative-to-specific-angle
\makeatletter
\tikzset{angle/.code 2 args=\pgfmathsincos{#1}\tikz@lib@place@handle@{#2}{180+#1}{\pgfmathresultx}{\pgfmathresulty}{#1}{1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[
        draw,fill,circle,
        %mininum size=3pt,
        inner sep=0pt,outer sep=3pt,
        label=above:{\scriptsize$a_{1,0}$}] (A0) {}; 
    \foreach \ang[
        count = \n,
        evaluate = \n as \prev using \n-1,
        evaluate = \ang as \labelang using {mod(450-30*\n,360)},
        %evaluate = \ang as \edgeang using {mod(450-30*\n,360)},
    ]in {330,300,...,60,30}{%
        \node[
            draw,fill,circle,
            inner sep=0pt,outer sep=3pt,
            label=\labelang:{\scriptsize$ a_{1,\n}$}
        ] (A\n) [angle={\ang}{of A\prev}] {} edge[-latex] node[swap] {\scriptsize$\alpha_{\n}$} (A\prev);
    }
    \draw[-latex] (A0) -- (A11);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Then I temporarily reset the outer sep=0pt. I want to label the edge of the dodecagon outside each edge of the circle, but I couldn't find an option like pos provided by \node when using
edge to set the label position $\alpha_{i,\n}$. In the below code, the label's position is not satisfactory.
The code:
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/729843/how-to-position-the-node-with-tikz-positioning-relative-to-specific-angle
\makeatletter
\tikzset{angle/.code 2 args=\pgfmathsincos{#1}\tikz@lib@place@handle@{#2}{180+#1}{\pgfmathresultx}{\pgfmathresulty}{#1}{1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[
        draw,fill,circle,
        %mininum size=3pt,
        inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,
        label=above:{\scriptsize$a_{1,0}$}] (A0) {}; 
    \foreach \ang[
        count = \n,
        evaluate = \n as \prev using \n-1,
        evaluate = \ang as \labelang using {mod(450-30*\n,360)},
        %evaluate = \ang as \edgeang using {mod(450-30*\n,360)},
    ]in {330,300,...,60,30}{%
        \node[
            draw,fill,circle,
            %mininum size=3pt,
            inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,
            label=\labelang:{\scriptsize$ a_{1,\n}$}
        ] (A\n) [angle={\ang}{of A\prev}] {} edge[-latex] node[swap] {\scriptsize$\alpha_{\n}$} (A\prev);
    }
    \draw[-latex] (A0) -- (A11);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Is there a better solution to plot the figure as above(like shape=regular polygon)? And could my code be changed with less clumsy code (more elegantly)?

you can use above, below, right, left etc. in the options for the edge nodes to position the labels.

I know these options to control the position of label, but in the \foreach, I think I shouldn't assign them manually to make them outside the edges.  I want a pos option. Or with another similar question, how to draw a clock panel with 12 numbers inside the circle?

Related: Q684351

You can also use degrees instead of left, above etc.

I have learnt about the link mentioned above, but there exists a lot of confusions to the loop and polar corrdinates using. Could you tell me some way to learn your code without justing searching in TikZ docs?

@Jasper Habicht Could you tell me the option or the keyword, I didn't found the pos in edge.

Maybe I did not understand correctly what you mean, but you could just use label=90:{foo} for label=above:{foo} or label=0:{foo} (or label=360:{foo}) for label=right:{foo}. So 0 is right and then it goes counterclockwise in degrees.

I am not sure, I understood everything correctly, but in my opinion, this can be done quite easily without calculating any angles:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=120]

    \foreach \i [count=\j from -1] in {0,...,11} {
        \node[fill, circle, inner sep=1pt, label={
            [circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=2.5em]{360/12*(\i-1/2)+120}:{\footnotesize $a_{1,\i}$}
        }] (a\i) at ({360/12*(\i-1/2)}:2) {};
        \ifnum\i=0\else
            \draw[latex-] (a\i) -- node[inner sep=0pt, circle, label={
                [circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=1.5em]{360/12*(\i-1)-60}:{$a_{\i}$}
            }] {} (a\j);
        \fi
    }
    \draw[latex-] (a0) -- node[inner sep=0pt, circle, label={
        [circle, inner sep=1pt]{-360/12-60}:{$a_{0}$}
    }] {} (a11);

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Or, if you really want to have everything perfectly aligned in terms of the angles and anchors, you could do like this:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    rotate=120, 
    every label/.style={
      circle, inner sep=0pt, anchor=center 
    }
  ]

    \foreach \i [count=\j from -1] in {0,...,11} {
        \node[fill, circle, inner sep=1pt, label={
            [minimum width=2.5em, label distance=-.5cm]
            {360/12*(\i-1/2)-60}:{\footnotesize $a_{1,\i}$}
        }] (a\i) at ({360/12*(\i-1/2)}:2) {};
        \ifnum\i=0\else
            \draw[latex-] (a\i) -- node[inner sep=0pt, circle, label={
                [minimum width=1.5em, label distance=.75em]
                {360/12*(\i-1)-60}:{$a_{\i}$}
            }] {} (a\j);
        \fi
    }
    \draw[latex-] (a0) -- node[inner sep=0pt, circle, label={
        [minimum width=1.5em, label distance=.75em]
        {-360/12-60}:{$a_{0}$}
    }] {} (a11);

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



So elegant and tricky with TikZ! What I want is the latter one, and the rotate usage is sooooo trikcy!

@Explorer Well, you need to "subtract" the rotation of the picture from the rotation of the labels which can be a bit tricky, but you could also let TikZ do these calculations, of course.
